# How to read reponse from iframe

Tags: html, angular

I am using form post in my code ,I am printing the response to the iframe but I am not able to read the
response from I frame.

```
let iframeDoc = this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument; is coming null


<form #myFormId action="http://baseurl/login" method="post" target="load_data">
  <label for="username">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br><br>
  <label for="password">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
  <button (click)="check($event)">Click</button>

</form>

<iframe #load_data name="load_data" (load)="onIFrameLoad($event)"   >


</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not read the content of iframe because of the security issue.

But you can communicate with an iframe using `Window.postMessage` API, please https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage for more information

Comment: I have seen this but how to post the reponse message from iframe to parent.The documents says sending a static message ,But i want to read the reponse from iframe.Could you please help me on this.

Comment: if you want to send message from iframe to the outer page use `parent.postMessage` parent refers to outer page

Comment: yeah but how to get the iframe data to pass in postmessage parameter .parent.postmessage(response,"*");  how to get that response that is being displayed in iframe.

Comment: `document.documentElement.innerHTML` inside iframe will return content

Comment: I am using angular application when i run this document.documentElement.innerHTML it is throwing entire application page.How can access only iframe data.

Answer (score 0):

If your parent application and application render in Iframe are not having the same origin (: :) then you wont be able to access the iframe content because of the security imposed by the browser.

If you can make ur iframe application to render from the same origin using proxy then you should be able to read the contentDocument property.

The more on this can be found at [Cross Window Communication](https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication)

Comment: my parent is just a form and the response I am printing on Iframe. when I checked the url both have the same origin, when the page is loading for the first time before submitting the form. After submitting to form, data is displayed on the iframe. Now it is throwing  Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:2022" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: Can you please elaborate making iframe application render from same origin using proxy.